# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+e^{2a}}\frac{1}{x^2+\pi^2}dx = \frac{2\pi e^{-a}}{4a^2+\pi^2}-\frac{1}{1+e^{2a}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

**Show that**\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+e^{2a}}\frac{1}{x^2+\pi^2}dx = \frac{2\pi e^{-a}}{4a^2+\pi^2}-\frac{1}{1+e^{2a}}
\end{align*}where $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

### My small try

Let $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{e^z}{(e^{2z}+e^{2a})z}$. Let $\Gamma$ be the positively oriented rectangle in the complex plane with vertices $R-i\pi$, $R+i\pi$, $-R+i\pi$ and $-R-i\pi$ where $R>|a|$. There are three first order poles of $f(z)$ lying inside $\Gamma$ at $z= 0, \frac{i\pi}{2}+a$ and $-\frac{i\pi}{2}+a$. Then, by the residue theorem, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_\Gamma f(z)\; dz &= 2\pi i \left( \mathop{\text{Res}}_{z=0} \; f(z) +  \mathop{\text{Res}}_{z=\frac{i\pi}{2}+a} \; f(z) +  \mathop{\text{Res}}_{z=-\frac{i\pi}{2}+a} \; f(z)\right) \\
&= 2\pi i \left( \frac{1}{1+e^{2a}} - \frac{i e^{-a}}{2a+i\pi} + \frac{i e^{-a}}{2a-i\pi}\right) \\
&= 2\pi i \left( \frac{1}{1+e^{2a}} - \frac{2\pi e^{-a}}{4a^2 +\pi^2}\right) \tag{1} 
\end{align*}

Comment: Where is the integral from?

Comment: you seem to have a solution. are you looking for other solutions? are you looking for verification? what is the purpose of your question?

Comment: I had a complete solution on my computer, but I lost it, not just a partial one. I posted the part that I remember.

Comment: If you use this $f(z) = \frac{e^z}{(e^{2z}+e^{2a})z}$, you can't get the integral you want.

Answer (score 8):

Substitute $t = e^x$, along with the shorthand $b= e^a$
\begin{align*}
I= &\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+e^{2a}}\frac{1}{x^2+\pi^2}dx =\int_0^\infty \frac1{(t^2+b^2)(\ln^2t+\pi^2)}dt\\
=& \int_0^\infty \frac{(1+t)-\frac{2b^2}{1+b^2}(t-\frac1t) }{(t^2+b^2)(\ln^2t+\pi^2) }
- \frac{\frac1{1+b^2}}{t( \ln^2t+\pi^2) }\ dt
\end{align*}
Then, utilize the integral expressions
$$\frac{1+t}{\ln^2t+\pi^2}= \frac1\pi\int_0^1 \sin(\pi y)t^{1-y}dy$$
$$\frac{t-\frac1t}{\ln^2t+\pi^2}=\frac2\pi\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi y)t^{1-2y}dy$$
and $ \int_0^\infty \frac1{t(\ln^2t+\pi^2)}dt=1 $
to evaluate
\begin{align*}
I= & \int_0^\infty \frac1{t^2+b^2}
\left(\frac1\pi\int_0^1 \sin\pi y \ {t^{1-y}}
-\frac{2b^2\sin2\pi y\ t^{1-2y}}{1+b^2}\  dy\right)dt\\
&\>\>\>\>\> -\frac1{1+b^2}\int_0^\infty \frac1{t(\ln^2t+\pi^2)}dt\\
  = & \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty
\frac{\sin\pi y \ {t^{1-y}}}{\pi(t^2+b^2)}
-\frac{2b^2\sin2\pi y\ t^{1-2y}}{\pi(1+b^2)(t^2+b^2)}\ dt\ dy-\frac1{1+b^2}\\
=& \int_0^1 \cos\frac{\pi y}2 b^{-y}dy 
 - \frac{2b^2}{1+b^2} \int_0^1 \cos\pi y\ b^{-2y}dy - \frac1{1+b^2}\\
=&\ \frac{2\pi+4b\ln b}{b(4\ln^2 b+\pi^2)}
-\frac{4\ln b}{4\ln^2 b+\pi^2}- \frac1{1+b^2}\\
 =&\ \frac{2\pi}{b(4\ln^2 b+\pi^2)}- \frac1{1+b^2}
= \frac{2\pi e^{-a}}{4a^2+\pi^2}-\frac{1}{1+e^{2a}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Very impressive solution!+1)

Comment: Unique solution as always (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $a\ge 0$. Let $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{e^z}{(e^{2z}+e^{2a})(z^2+\pi^2)}$. Then $f(z)$ will have poles
$$ z=\pi i, z_k=(k+\frac12)\pi i+a,k=0,1,2,\cdots.$$
in the upper half plane.

Set $R_n=\sqrt{(k+1)^2\pi^2+a^2}$. Let $\Gamma_n$ be the union of the upper semi-circle $\gamma_n$ with radius $R_n$ centered at $0$ and the segment from $-R_n$ to $R_n$. Clearly $f(z)$ has poles
$$ z=\pi i, z_k=(k+\frac12)\pi i+a,k=0,1,2,\cdots, n $$
and analytic in $\gamma_n$.
Then
\begin{align*}
\int_{-R_n}^{R_n}f(x)dx+\int_{\gamma_n} f(z)\; dz &= 2\pi i \left( \mathop{\text{Res}}_{z=\pi i} \; f(z) +  \sum_{k=0}^n\mathop{\text{Res}}_{z=z_k} \; f(z)\right) \\
&= 2\pi i \left( \frac{i}{2\pi(1+e^{2a})}+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{i (-1)^{k+1}e^{-a}}{2} \frac{1}{z_k^2+\pi^2}\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{1+e^{2a}}+\pi e^{-a}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{k}}{z_k^2+\pi^2}.
\end{align*}
Now letting $n\to\infty$ gives
\begin{align*}
\int_\infty^\infty f(x)\; dx &=-\frac{1}{1+e^{2a}}+\pi e^{-a}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{z_k^2+\pi^2}.
\end{align*}
Note
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{z_k^2+\pi^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{((k+\frac12)\pi i+a)^2+\pi^2}\\
&=&\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \frac{1}{(k+(\frac12-\frac{ai}{\pi}))^2-1}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{k-\frac12-\frac{ai}{\pi}}-\frac{1}{k+\frac{3}2-\frac{ai}{\pi}}\bigg)\\
&=&-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\bigg(\frac{1}{-\frac12-\frac{ai}{\pi}}-\frac{1}{\frac12-\frac{ai}{\pi}}\bigg)\\
&=&\frac{2}{4a^2+\pi^2}. 
\end{eqnarray}$$